# how to use django-autocomplete-light for admin filter

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

I'm wondering whether it is possible to use django-autocomplete-light in the admin filter. If it is possible, then how?

I tried

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'birth_country': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='country-autocomplete')
        }
```

from the [documentation](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-in-the-admin) but it only adds autocomplete to the form content, not the admin filter.